# Angular How call/instantiate a component from a regular typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to start or call to a component if is possible from a regular typescript class and pass it data.

My regular class:

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    const myModel = new MyModel();
    myModel.setName('Peter');
    const component = new DashComponent(dashModel);
  }
}
```

But this doesn't load the component on the browser.

If I use router.navigate() I can initialize the component, but the think is I want to pass data too in the constructor.

Thank you.

Comment: Follow some tutorials first.

Comment: See this https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader